# How can I select two columns in a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, select

Imagine I got 2 df, named A and B. For each row of df A, I'd like to check if there is the respective row in B df. In the example below, the code would print me only one answer TRUE, because the last row in df A do not match with the last row in df B.

```
A <- NULL
B <- NULL
A <- data.frame(A = c('a','b','c','d','e'), B = c('1','2','3','4','5'))
B <- data.frame(A = c('a','b','c','d','f'), B = c('1','2','3','4','5'))

i <- 0
for(i in 1: length(A$A))
{
  point <- A[i,]
  if(!point %in% B[which[1:2]])
    print(TRUE)
}
```

Comment: What do you want? Just to check if both the dataframes are exactly the same or how many rows are identical?

Comment: @Sonny, I need to loop all rows in df A checking if there's a different row in df B but without using a looping. It must get the 2 columns from each other to be compared.

Comment: @d.b it didn't work!

Comment: @d.b if the row selected in df A is NOT found in df B, a message must be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool = Reduce(paste, A) %in% Reduce(paste, B)
transform(A, msg = c("Absent", "Present")[bool + 1])
#  A B     msg
#1 a 1 Present
#2 b 2 Present
#3 c 3 Present
#4 d 4 Present
#5 e 5  Absent
```

Comment: Actualy I was not supposed to add a 3th colum in any df. It's even simpler: just assure for each row in A is checked in all row in df B. If not found, display a msg.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the anti-join of the two tables contains any rows (i.e. if there are any rows not equal between the two data frames on the common columns), and print `TRUE` if so

```
if(diff_rows <- nrow(dplyr::anti_join(A, B)) > 0) print(diff_rows)

# Joining, by = c("A", "B")
# [1] TRUE
# Warning message:
# Column `A` joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector
```

You can clean up the output some if you want to ignore warnings

```
if(diff_rows <- nrow(suppressWarnings(dplyr::anti_join(A, B, by = names(A)))) > 0) 
  print(diff_rows)

# [1] TRUE
```